# Is there a centralized history file for all the commands run from various terminals?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

I am aware that every terminal has it's separate history,which can be viewed by the history command. Commands issued on suppose terminal tty1 will be shown in the history of tty1 only and not in the history of any other terminal suppose tty2.

Is there a file which stores all the commands fired from various different terminals; irrespective of the terminal type (tty,pts1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command History is generally a feature provided by *bash*, and is stored *per-user* in the `.bash_history` file in your home directory.

While the `history` command may show you different histories in different terminals while those terminals are open, they will all be merged and written to the common `~/.bash_history` file once you exit the terminals.

Comment: so does it mean that after reboot I will be able to see the history of all the commands issued from various different terminals on each and every terminal?

Comment: Yes, certainly after reboot the histories will be the same since they will all come from the same `.bash_history` file.